# How to access instance in vue3 composition API lifecycle hooks

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I stumbled into a totally unexpected problem while refactoring my code to composition API: there doesn't seem to be any (documented) way of accessing current instance from the lifecycle hooks.

sample code:

```js
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    onMounted(() => { 
      console.log(this);  // <-- will be undefined
    });
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this);  // <-- will be the component
  },
}
```

I've spent hours trying to find a solution to this and ultimately just used the old options API to get what I want. None of examples, tutorials or documentation - that I read - use `this` in the hooks.

But I find it unbelievable that only undocumented `getCurrentInstance` would be the way to get the current instance from the hook.

So, which doc did I miss?

Comment: Option API holds every component in an object. Composition API compose components made from setup function. If you don't use `onMounted()` web hook in setup function, the component won't have a `onMounted()` lifecycle hook. Some life cycle hooks are gone because `setup()` is a life cycle hook itself, so you won't have `beforeCreate()` and `created()` hooks.

Comment: The reason you can't access `this` in the setup function is that you don't need it anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is the same example with a component

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue;

const MyComponent = {
  setup() {
    const id = ref(Math.round(Math.random() * 100000));        
    const count = ref(0);        
    const plus = () => { count.value++; }        
    const minus = function() { count.value--; }        
    
    onMounted(() => { 
      count.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
    });    
    
    return {id, count, plus, minus }
  },
  template: `id: {{id}} &nbsp; <button type="button" @click="minus()">-1</button>
    &nbsp;{{count}}&nbsp;
    <button type="button" @click="plus()">+1</button><hr/>`   
}

const App = {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">        
   <my-component v-for="i in 5" />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

What for do you need `this` in the component?

If you create your component with [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html), then you can access all the properties directly, without using `this`.

Here is a very basic example:

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {    

    const count = ref(0);        
    const up = () => { count.value++; }        
    const down = function() { count.value--; }    
    
    onMounted(() => { 
      count.value = 10
    });    
    
    return {count, up, down }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">        
    <button type="button" @click="down()">-1</button>
    {{count}}
    <button type="button" @click="up()">+1</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need this to be able to assign a unique ID to each instance and then check for that ID in render function. I believe your `count` variable provides a global variable that all instances share, not a per-instance variable.

Comment: Then simply move the `count` variable to the component.

Comment: I can see now that setup() is actually `create` from vue 2. variables used in setup are unique to instance already. Your answer was correct from the start and I have been reading the docs poorly...