# Vue js dev Environment - require rebuild application to see html and css changes

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

-Hello I am new in Vue, I am building VueJS application in SPA with SFC, I was wondering if there is any way to see html changes without rebuild the application again, changes in all file reflect immediately but changes in html and css required execute npm run dev again.

- I use Vue3, js and bootstrap only, I am not using nodejs or typescript.

I need some way to make my changes reflect on html after saving file with out rebuilding the application.

Comment: There are a few ways to see changes in HTML and CSS without rebuilding the application.　`Hot Reloading`, `Browser extension` , `Webpack`.

Comment: It is possible to create apps with Vue and Components without any builder. Here is an example of the simplest Vue app https://stackoverflow.com/a/75099602/2487565. Of course it does make sense only for developing/debugging.

Comment: Has this been happening for a long time? Sometimes it happens with my development also, so I stop my server, clear my cache, restart the server, do a hot reload, and everything gets rectified.
You could try that also.

Comment: @Tolbxela thanks for answering, But could I do this with Vusjd SPA too?

Comment: @moe_rayo Thanks, I am already doing that but Is there any way to make Vue do this auto.

Comment: Originally, Vue does it automatically. I wonder what could be affecting it @abdekrazekmostafa